# How to change the background of a MaterialDesign ListBoxItem in XAML? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design

I am trying to change the background color of the MaterialDesign ListBoxItem style but I can't get it to work.

I know about overriding the style like this :

```xml
<Style x:Key="MaterialDesignListBoxItem"
       TargetType="ListBoxItem"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}">
            
</Style>
```

But I won't get the MaterialDesign animations as it will just be a regular button.

Is there any way to change the background color and keep the MaterialDesign look and feel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the `ListBox` to a custom `Style` that is based on `MaterialDesignListBoxItem`, e.g.:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That only seems to set the currently selected `ListBoxItem`'s background color.

Comment: No. Do you have another style somewhere? Please provide a repo of your issue if you cannot get it to work. The above works for me using the latest version of the `MaterialDesignThemes` package.

Comment: My bad, I was actually applying the `MaterialDesignNavigationListBoxItem` style and not the regular `MaterialDesignListBoxItem`. Could it be possible to make it work with the first style ?

Comment: That's a different question with a different solution I guess.